# SQL to retrieve second row from a table where secondary key matches based on primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry I'm struggling to word this problem properly which might be part of the reason I cannot find the answer.

So, I have 2 tables in a database that is not normalised however I am not allowed to redesign the database. I just need to write a query  to obtain the data I need.

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts (
contactID int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
objectID int(4) NOT NULL,
contactItem varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Persons(
personID int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
primaryContactID int(4) NOT NULL
);
```

The tables are linked by Contacts.contactID and Persons.primaryContactID. So it's easy to query for the primary contact entry which is always the persons email address using a simple join.

But then for each contact there is a second entry for their phone number.  Contacts.objectID enables you to find the 2nd entry.

Eg-

Contacts tabe-

```
    +---------+----------+-------------
    | contactID | objectID | contactItem 
    +-----------+----------+-------------
    | 1         | 1        | him@gmail.com
    | 2         | 1        | 07855111111
    +-----------+----------+-------------
```

What SQL query could I use to return both of these items not just the  primary contact?

```
pseudo- 
get primary contact id
get object ID
search for the object ID in the table
return the two rows based on object ID
```

Comment: You should be far along enough to have tried something already. Post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
select personID, contactID, objectID, contactItem
from Persons 
inner join Contacts on objectID in 
  (select objectID from Contacts pk where pk.contactID = primaryContactID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a Select joining both tables like this:

```
Select Contacts.*, Persons.*
from Contacts
inner join Persons on Contacts.contactId = Persons.primaryContactID
where Contacts.objectID = [something you want here]
```

Comment: IP doesn't know the objectID in question though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Contacts` 
WHERE  `objectID` 
IN (

SELECT  `objectID` 
FROM  `Contacts` 
WHERE  `contactID` = x
)
```

It will get all with the same objectid from contacts as the contactid you search.

Answer (score 0):

With joins only:

```
select personid, c1.contactitem, c2.contactitem
from persons p
left join contacts c1 on c1.contactid = primarycontactid
left join contacts c2 on c2.objectid = c1.objectid and c2.contactid <> c1.contactid;
```

Result:

```
 personid | contactitem | contactitem 
----------+-------------+-------------
       42 | gmail       | 205324
       86 | hotmail     | 5320
(2 rows)
```